# Faces on a rotating cube

Tags: combinatorics, solid-geometry, rubiks-cube

This one is probably a softball question, but...

- Fact: A cube has 6 faces
- Fact (unless my math is wrong): A cube that is cut in half center horizontal can be reoriented to have 18 unique faces.  (The top and bottom stay the same.  The other four sides have 16 combinations: A/A, B/B, C/C, D/D, A/B, A/C, A/D, B/A, B/C, B/D, C/A, C/B, C/D, D/A, D/B, D/C)
- Question: How many faces could the cube have if it is cut center horizontal and center vertical?

Constraint: You cannot "lift a piece" out of the cube and reorient it.  The entire cube must be rotated, like a Rubik Cube.

**Correction:**  It would have to be cut center vertical along the front and the side.  Otherwise it doesn't rotate properly!  So in otherwords, it is a 2x2 Rubik Cube instead of a 3x3 Rubik Cube.

Comment: I'm not seeing how the second bullet works - how are you cutting it in half?  A straight cut can't add more than 8 faces - two for the interior of the cut, and each face is cut in half. So you can't get more than 14 faces when cutting a cube with a plane cut.

Comment: For some reason I can't visualize it all that well, but imagine a D6 die.  If you cut it along the 2/3/4/5, the 1 and 6 face would be unchanged.  But you could rotate it so that the faces are 2 upper/2 lower, 2U/3L, 2U/4L, 2U/5L, 3U/3L, 3U/4L, 3U/5L, 3U/6L, etc... so 16 combinations.  Plus the 1 and 6 face, for a total of 18 possible faces.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The question isn't about cutting to expose new faces. it's about breaking the cube into subhedra that can rotate like on a Rubik's cube.  A $2\times2\times2$ Rubik's cube can be thought of as a standard cube with three perpendicular plane cuts through the center.  Such a cube has a certain (large) number of configurations for each face.  OP wants to know how many configurations there are of the faces of a similar cube with only *two* perpendicular cuts instead of three.

Comment: @MJD Thanks. Still having trouble visualizing, but that seems at least visually clearer :)

Comment: @Anthony I need a clarification here.  Suppose The top face is all red, and is divided into four small red squares by the two cuts.  I mark the small red squares with numerals 1–4.  Then I manipulate the cube so that the top face is once again completely red, but the numerals have moved around.  Does this count as the same configuration as before (since it's still entirely red) or different (since the red squares moved around)?

Comment: @MJD Good question.  No, reorienting a solid face would not count.  That being, an all red top numbered (going clockwise) 1,2,3,4 being rotated to be 4,1,2,3 would still count as the same face.  If it was changed to be half red, half green, however - that would be considered a new face.